# Costa Rica 6 hr taxi ride from Playa Carrillo to SJO at 4am

Tags: airport-transfer, costa-rica, sjo

We're traveling to Costa Rica and tour suggested we take taxi to airport for our 12 noon flight. They said to allow 6 hours which means a 4 AM depart from Playa Carrillo. Is it safe to do this? Would taking a hotel in San Jose be advised? Is 6 hours enough time? I have safety concerns.

Comment: 6 hours for what? for the drive plus all airport process? or only the latter? And I don't know Playa Carrillo but in the end I guess it is in Costa Rica, so you are travelling THROUGH Costa Rica to the SJO airport by cab, not TO Costa Rica? Is that right?

Comment: We were told to consider 6 hours travel time to be at airport 2 hours before our noon flight...To be there for 10am, they suggest leaving the Playa Carrillo area hotel to go to SJO airport at 4am. I won't be driving but worried about if the roads are safe as far as lighting, pavement, I don't know it this is rustic area...?? Alternative is spring for hotel in San Jose the evening before...

Answer (score 3):

I've taken a taxi tour in Costa Rica that started around the same time, and was closer to the Nicaragua border, and had no trouble. So I wouldn't be concerned about safety, or at least no more than I would travelling the previous day. Make sure you organize it through your hotel and get them to pick you up there.

Your tour guide is going to have a much better idea of travelling time than we do, and six hours doesn't look grossly off either way.